# How can I fix iPhone viewport error causing in React website

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iphone, viewport

I have made a Navigation bar in react which had two components one for mobile navigation and one for desktop navigation, and I m conditionally rendering both according to the width of the device. But for some reason, it's not working on IOS, but working on other android devices properly.

here is the code.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(
    window.matchMedia("(max-width:1024px").matches
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      setIsMobile(window.matchMedia("(max-width:1024px").matches);
    });
  });

  return <div>{isMobile ? <Mobnav /> : <DesktopNavbar />}</div>;
};
```

and here is the iPhone image of the website :
[image]

and here how it should be
[image]

I did have added the meta tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Comment: [This is the solution which worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719526/safari-ignore-window-matchmedia)

Comment: It was a typo mistake for more detail have a watch on this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719526/safari-ignore-window-matchmedia